# YouAskOverflow - StackOverflow For SMS (placeholder)

Tags: app, questions, placeholder

### About

SMS for receiving/posting questions on Stack Overflow

#### Platform

What platform or browser is your app for?
Web based

### Contact

Who created this app? Who are the key contributors?
How do we get in touch with them or find them?

youaskoverflow@gmail.com

Comment: This was flagged as a stale placeholder. See [this answer](https://stackapps.com/a/7591) for more information.