# Pyle: A Stack Exchange client for UWP (Beta)

Tags: app, windows-uwp

Currently under development, in open beta [on the Store](https://www.microsoft.com/store/apps/9NBXPVGQDG7F).
If you'd like an invitation to the Slack beta-testers team for quicker and more direct communication, just let me know.

[image: Dashboard]
[image: Browse and vote]
[image: Earn achievements]

Comment: This was flagged as a [stale placeholder](https://stackapps.com/a/7591) but it appears to be an okay beta.

Comment: @BrockAdams Sadly, it has gone stale. I fully intend to work on it again... Someday. But right now I do not have the time :(.

Comment: Does it work at all?  If not, it should be tagged [obsolete] until it does.

Comment: @BrockAdams I haven't tested it lately, but there's no reason it shouldn't still work.