# PLACEHOLDER - Broken Link Repairer

Tags: app, placeholder

In the coming weeks, I'll be modifying the [Broken Image Repairer](https://gist.github.com/Glorfindel83/9d954d34385d2ac2597bbe864466259f) so that it can be used to mass-edit broken links. Examples where it could be used:

- German Language: [canoo.net has been moved to canoonet.eu](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1506/15821)
- Meta Stack Exchange: [old feature requests on Stack Exchange's UserVoice channel](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7546730)

Editing bumps posts, so this operation should be done with a certain rate limit, after reaching a consensus on a site's own meta.

Comment: So, per [a Q that somebody asked](https://stackapps.com/q/7490) and its "official" answer, should we nuke this question in about 9 days? ;)

Comment: I have a no-expiry write-access token now; if deleting this question doesn't invalidate the token, I probably wouldn't even notice :)

Comment: That's an interesting question and potentially a bug.  You should totally test if deleting this Q invalidates the token.  (Maybe even give it a week, for any batch jobs to run.)

Comment: Yeah, the write access of the token is revoked immediately (it continues to work for things like your inbox).

Comment: This was flagged as a stale placeholder. See [this answer](https://stackapps.com/a/7591) for more information.  Does placing this post on hold affect write access?  Also, if still needed and still private -- even the source code -- then we should probably come up with some kind of standard for private apps.

Comment: Looks like it's still working: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/50406 – might be caching though, I'll try again tomorrow. I don't mind this question being closed, but I might need an upvote to prevent it from getting roomba'd :P

Comment: Might also morph it into a [meta] post about apps and closure. Or, do it as a private app...

Comment: @BrockAdams [posted a self-answered question about it](https://stackapps.com/q/8394/34061).

Comment: Great; and do you want to keep this post a private app, or do you plan to release code or something?

Comment: I have some plans to modify the Broken Image Repairer into something which can be used to mass-update broken links ([here](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1506/15821) is an example, partially in German). Depending on the volume, it should be done with an account with edit privileges, which I don't have on all sites :) Anyway, since this question has more than 1 comment, it's protected from Roomba, so you can leave it this way for now.