# Does a closed and/or deleted Stack Apps post still provide access to the API?

Tags: support, api-v2.2, authentication, api-key, write-access

[Registering your application](https://stackapps.com/apps/oauth/register) as a Stack Apps [app](/questions/tagged/app) is necessary in order to obtain a [higher request quota](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/throttle), [authentication](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication) and [write access to the API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/write).

What happens if the question is [closed because of being a placeholder question](https://stackapps.com/a/7591/34061), and when it's deleted (e.g. by [Roomba](https://stackapps.com/help/roomba))? Does the app still qualify for those registration benefits?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've just done a couple of tests with my [placeholder app](https://stackapps.com/q/8039/34061). Even though the question is closed, I was able to generate a new access token (following the [regular procedure](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication)) for my sockpuppet account, and with it I was able to [edit an answer in the Sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/327624/revisions). The token for my regular account continues to work as well.

When the post is deleted, write access is revoked; you'll get an error message:

> {"error_message":"Applications must have a registered Stack Apps post to write","error_name":"access_denied","error_id":403}

Read-only access (e.g. access to the user's [global inbox](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/inbox)) continues to work, and acquiring a new token is also possible.

P.S. if you ever decide to test this by deleting and undeleting your question, don't forget to re-add its URL to the [application listing](https://stackapps.com/apps/oauth/).