# How to 'publish' an app after the development is complete?

Tags: support, stackapps

I followed the steps and created a StackApp (registering a new OAuth app) and added a StackApp post as per question - [My app has to be published first? But it's still under development](https://stackapps.com/questions/4573/my-app-has-to-be-published-first-but-its-still-under-development)

Now that my development is complete, my application can call Stack Exchange APIs successfully. Should I leave the StackApp post as it is and the app registration as it is? I'm looking to see if I need to do anything next on the OAuth app.

[image: StackApps Post screenshot from oauth app]

Answer (score 4):

You should update your [placeholder post](https://stackapps.com/questions/8756/placeholder-api-poc) to reflect the latest developments. You can use the template to know which information could be useful for potential users of your application. Otherwise, your placeholder question may be closed for the following reason:

> This is a placeholder question for an app that's still under development; it will be deleted within 9 days unless regularly edited to show progress on development. If the app is ready for others to use, [fill in the template](https://stackapps.com/questions/7/how-to-list-your-application-library-wrapper-script-here) and flag for moderator attention to indicate that this post can be reopened.

(The 9 days requirement isn't strictly enforced anymore, but the idea still holds.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Basically after the development, I should update the StackApp post with the template and because of the update the post will never be closed / deleted? 

If the StackApp post is closed / deleted, will my application stop having write access?

Comment: If it's deleted, you'll no longer have write access. Closure doesn't matter; see [Does a closed and/or deleted Stack Apps post still provide access to the API?](https://stackapps.com/q/8394/34061) App posts with sufficient detail may be closed if the project is clearly abandoned and the app no longer works; AFAIK they're never deleted.