# App post got deleted

Tags: support, api-v2.2, oauth2, write-access

I'm currently writing an app using the Stack Exchange API.

Today I wanted to rework the login component, but after signing in I get the following message:

> Application must have a registered Stack Apps post to write

That kinda confused me because I used this app one day ago. So I went to my [post page](https://stackapps.com/users/64628/norbert-bartko?tab=questions) and the post was gone, my App is still registered under the [Manage your applications](https://stackapps.com/apps/oauth) page.

So my questions are:

- Why is my app post deleted?
- Should I just create a new post to get API access?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is my app post deleted?

My guess is that [an automated process](https://stackapps.com/help/roomba) did this. You can still view the post, just copy the URL from the 'Manage your applications' page. If it has a banner 'deleted by Community ♦' that's the case.

> Should I just create a new post to get API access?

That's fine (it's not that we're flooded with new posts every day). Something that helps to avoid this in the future is to properly document your app, instead of only using a [placeholder](/questions/tagged/placeholder). It's more likely to receive an upvote (at least from me) and questions with a positive score are never deleted automatically. (If you already did this, perhaps I missed the post.)

Comment: I checked my 'Stack Apps Post' entry on the 'Manage your applications' page and it was empty. Set it to the deleted question and all works fine again. Is that workaround intended to work?

Comment: I will create a new post any way

Comment: Not sure, but I tried that once: https://stackapps.com/q/8394/34061

Comment: Interesting indeed! The API isn't really actively maintained anymore, so we have to work with what we already have. If it's still working for you, all the better.