# When are Stack Apps questions shown with thumbnails instead of regular statistics?

Tags: support, questions, tags, meta

Today I was browsing [a tag here](https://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/placeholder?tab=newest) and I noticed that on the first pages, all questions are shown with thumbnails (most of the time, just the default one):

[image]

However, from [page 5 on](https://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/placeholder?tab=newest&page=5&pagesize=15) the formatting is like on other Stack Exchange sites, showing votes, answers and views instead of the thumbnail:

[image]

It does not seem to matter whether a template is being used; [this app of mine](https://stackapps.com/q/8039/34061) doesn't use it but it's still shown with a default thumbnail.

The behaviour is reproducible for a few other tags, e.g. [[greasemonkey]](https://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/greasemonkey?tab=newest).

Comment: I _think_ it's just whenever the current page of results only contains entries with [app], [script], or [library] tags (and any number of "non-primary" tags)? But I'm not positive; i.e. as soon as there's one result with [discussion] or something it turns to the non-thumbnail view. Someone might be able to Science™ and confirm

Comment: @TimStone confirmed for both examples and [tag:stackoverflow]; my guess is you're right.