# PLACEHOLDER - DataWeave Slack-Stack

Tags: app, placeholder

Read questions about DataWeave in Stack Overflow and post it into a channel in Slack. A response in that channel creates an answer in Stack Overflow.

The app is not yet ready for prime time.

Comment: This was flagged as a stale placeholder. See [this answer](https://stackapps.com/a/7591) for more information.