# PLACEHOLDER - FroloStack - simple Stack Overflow client for Android

Tags: app, placeholder, android

This is a simple Stack Overflow client for Android. It allows users to search questions, answers of questions and other users.
Also users will be able to add their answers to a question.
it is still in development.

Comment: This was flagged as a stale placeholder. See [this answer](https://stackapps.com/a/7591) for more information.